# Save multiple sheets from one workbook to individual folders

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with many sheets, both hidden and visible. 
I need to copy all but the first sheet to individual folders that are not created

In the original workbook I have :master sheet, sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3, etc
every sheet has a title inside the sheet at cell A1

I want to copy all EXCEPT master sheet and the hidden sheets.

I need to save the sheets to individual workbooks

```
U:\folder
   \sheet 1
   \sheet 2
   \sheet 3
```

I am so confused. I know i need a loop to go through the sheets, I need a loop to save and set the name variable from the sheet as it runs through the loop, and then it also has to create the folders if needed.

I am so lost in how to mesh that many loops and commands. I can see the overall outline but I am getting lost.

I would really appreciate the help.

I've tried several individual solutions but I have NO idea how to incorporate all of them.

'some of the code i found online I've been trying to merge together to one

```
'copy only visible sheets
Sub saveVisibleSheetsAsXLSM()       'saves all visible sheets as new xlsx files
    Const exportPath = "x:\yourDestinationPath\"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets                      'for each worksheet
        If ws.Visible Then                                  'if it's visible:
            Debug.Print "Exporting: " & ws.Name
            ws.Copy '(if no params specified, COPY creates + activates a new wb)
            Set wbNew = Application.ActiveWorkbook          'get new wb object
            wbNew.SaveAs exportPath & ws.Name & ".xlsm", 52 'save new wb
            wbNew.Close                                     'close new wb
            Set wbNew = Nothing                             'cleanup 
        End If
    Next ws
    Set ws = Nothing                                        'clean up 
End Sub


'skip first sheet code
Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count

            ' Insert your code here.
            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
            MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

         Next I

      End Sub
```

Comment: Create folder, Set folder location, Loop over worksheets and set filename, copy sheet to new workbook, save using the folder location and filename variables, continue with next iteration. - if only starting from one workbook then you only need one loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything was right with your code except the **Folder Paths**.

Use `MkDir` to create a Folder and then save the Files in it. Use `AND` in If condition to skip the `Master Sheet`. I have amended the code.

**Code:**

```
Sub saveVisibleSheetsAsXLSM()

    Const exportPath = "x:\yourDestinationPath\" '**Change your Path HERE**

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Visible And Not ws.Name = "master sheet" Then '**Check the spelling of Master Sheet**
            Debug.Print "Exporting: " & ws.Name
                ws.Copy
            Set wbNew = Application.ActiveWorkbook
            MkDir exportPath & ws.Name
            wbNew.SaveAs exportPath & ws.Name & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsm", 52
            wbNew.Close
            Set wbNew = Nothing
        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Did this Work ? If not I will remove the Answer.